# How to access the value of every single row pandas dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I create a dictionary from a dataset and now I want to access every single row of the dictionary. Every single row of this dictionary contains 2 names, ex:  Winner: Alex  Loser: Leo.
My problem is that I don't know how to access the 2 names by index.

I would like something like this:
Row 1: Winner: Alex
       Loser: Leo
and I would like to access the row like this:  dictionary[x] -> so I can get the row and then once I have the row I want to access it like a=raw[y] and b=raw[y+1]. And then I want to print A and B. I want to do this because I have to copy just one specific player from every single row and to save it into another dictionary.

This is the code that I wrote to create the dictionary and to access it but doesn't work as I want.

```
dicti= imd4.to_dict('index') // dicti  is the dictionary that I created and imd4 is the dataset containing the Winner and the Loser name
for x in dicti:
print (x,':')
for y in dicti[x]:
    a=dicti[x][y]
    b=dicti[x][y+1]    //I can't do this  but I would like to do it. So I can save the data base on their index 
    print (y,':',dicti[x][y])
    print('Test :' ,a)
```

[Here you can see how the dataset is build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul78W.png)
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you transforming the DataFrame into a dictionary for this? Where is the [mcve]? What do _but doesn't work as I want_ and _I can't do this_ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's set up a test dictionary:

```
test_dictionary=[
     {'winner':'ross','loser:'chandler'},
     {'winner':'rachael','loser:'phoebe'},
     {'winner':'joey','loser:'monica'},
     {'winner':'gunther','loser:'chandler'}
]
```

We can loop through this easily:

```
for contest in test_dictionary:
    print (contest)
```

and we could add a line number using the enumerate function:

```
for line_number, contect in test_dictionary:
    print (line_number,contest)
```

so now we have the line number we can easily access the next element - we have to bear in mind though we don't want to access the final element as we can't print the contest after this so we loop to the [-1] element:

```
for line_number, contect in test_dictionary[:-1]:
    print (line_number,contest)
    print (line_number+1,test_dictionary[line_number+1])
```

We could also simply use a range on the length of test_dictionary and access the elements directly:

```
for line_number in range(len(test_dictionary)-1]:
    print (line_number,test_dictionary[line_number])
    print (line_number+1,test_dictionary[line_number+1])
```